# How to use binary/bitfield literals in a MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

```
select (bin(~'101010101010101')) as Result;

Result is : '1111111111111111101001000010000111000000110011111000000101001010'
```

Is it true?

I expect to see this result:

> '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010101010101010'

Help me please.

Comment: What language is this? C/C++? Ada? Pascal? BASIC? FORTRAN? Common Lisp? LOLcode?

Comment: Some SQL dialect? If so, what database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string to a bitwise operation. [These operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html) are defined for BIGINT integers in mysql, so you might get unexpected results.

You should try:

```
SELECT bin(~0x5555) as Result
```

or:

```
SELECT bin(~b'101010101010101' ) as Result
```

Results in:

```
'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010101010101010'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 101010101010101 is interpreted as decimal number. Its binary representation is 10110111101111000111111001100000111111010110101. Complement this and you get the printed result.